# Can oauth access tokens migrate?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have very little experience with Oauth 2.0 and am trying to better understand how the system works. Are access tokens tied to a user/device/session? For example, can I migrate an access token granted for one app and use it in another app? How will the server/API know? I believe most APIs have apps request using an app_ID, is there any other data that goes into a request for a  token?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The OAuth 2.0 protocol framework is designed to allow for different types of access tokens but the only access token that has been standardized so far is the so-called "Bearer" token, so I'm assuming your question is about that.

A Bearer token is opaque to the Client which means that it is just an "identifier" or "string" that the Client passes on to the Resource Server to get access to protected resources. This also means that it is not specifically tied to a device/session or Client. In fact anyone who gets a hold of the Bearer token can actually use it to get access to the protected resources. This is one of the known drawbacks of Bearer tokens but it makes it very easy to implement them. It relies on a secure HTTPs channel for confidentiality.

The previous paragraph describes how to *use* a Bearer token. The process that the Client has to go through to *obtain* such a token, may include presenting a Client identifier and a Client secret to the Authorization Server indeed. But the Resource Server (aka. Server or API) does not know or care how the Client obtained the Bearer token.

There are token extensions of OAuth 2.0 under development that would require the Client to proof that it is the rightful owner of the token. Such tokens are called "Proof of Possession" Tokens and may be useful in environments that have higher security requirements. See: http://www.thread-safe.com/2015/01/proof-of-possession-putting-pieces.html

Comment: Perfect, thank you! That's exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: Please accept user's answer if it solved your issue as a sign of consideration for the time he put on answering :)